# How do I determine the length of a routine on ARMv7?

Tags: disassembly, arm

I am disassembling and reverse engineering the logic of an assembly routine written in ARMv7 (hope I'm using the right terminology, as I'm a newbie for this particular processor).

In doing so, I came across this site: [Introduction to ARM](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/pc.html). In order to determine how much code I need to disassemble, first, I need to determine the length of the code. It is my understanding that I only need to look for `[Bxx][2]` (branch) instructions and instructions that alter the PC (program counter), for example,

- `MOV PC, r14`
- `POP {r4, r5, pc}`

Can someone please advise if I have missed out any instructions that I need to look out for? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what IDA considers a return in ARM:

- `RET` (=`MOV PC, LR`)
- `POP {reglist}` if `reglist` includes `LR` or `PC`
- `LDMFD SP, {reglist}`, `LDMED SP, {reglist}` or `LDMDB R11, {reglist}` if `reglist` includes `LR` or `PC`
- `LDR PC, [SP], #4`
- `BX LR`
- `BX reg` if preceded by `POP {reglist}` and `reglist` includes `reg`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there may be something like:

```
.text:00192CB6                 POP             {R4}
.text:00192CB8                 B.W             sub_268508
.text:00192CB8 ; End of function XXX::YYY::zZz(void)
```

IIRC I also have seen conditional branches leading outside of what I would expect to be function boundaries, but I cannot find any example now.